Horizontal Scroll inside PageCurl
The problem is that you can't use the real pageCurl swipe when you go to another picture, but the pageCurl swipe only works on the edges of the screen. In the first image of doublePager, it must only be possible to go back and in the second image of doublePAger to the next pageCurl screen. Currently pageCurl only works on the top or bottom of the screen, and it would work over the entire edge of the screen
emulator screenShot
var currentIndex by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
    var isFirstPage by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

    val state = rememberPageCurlState()
    val rowState = rememberScrollState()
    val config = rememberPageCurlConfig(
        dragForwardEnabled = false,
        tapForwardEnabled = false,
        tapBackwardEnabled = false
    )
    val configFirstIndex = rememberPageCurlConfig(
        dragBackwardEnabled = false,
        tapForwardEnabled = false,
        tapBackwardEnabled = false
    )

    PageCurl(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        count = images.size,
        state = state,
        config = if (currentIndex == 0) config else configFirstIndex
    ) { indexPage ->
        if (indexPage != 0 && indexPage != images.size) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(Color.Black)
            ) {
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .horizontalScroll(state = rowState)
                ) {
                    AsyncImage(
                        model = images[indexPage],
                        placeholder = null,
                        error = null,
                        contentDescription = "The delasign logo",
                        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .background(Color.Black)
                    )
                    AsyncImage(
                        model = "https://delasign.com/delasignBlack.png",
                        placeholder = null,
                        error = null,
                        contentDescription = "The delasign logo",
                        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .background(Color.Black)
                    )
                }
                LaunchedEffect(key1 = rowState.value) {
                    currentIndex = if (rowState.value > 975 || isFirstPage) 1 else 0
                }
            }
            LaunchedEffect(key1 = state) {
                if (state.progress <= -0.65) {
                    rowState.scrollTo(rowState.maxValue)
                    isFirstPage = false
                    currentIndex = 0
                } else if (state.progress >= 0.65) {
                    rowState.scrollTo((rowState.value - 10000f).toInt())
                    isFirstPage = false
                    currentIndex = 1
                }
            }
        } else {
            isFirstPage = true
            AsyncImage(
                model = images[indexPage],
                placeholder = null,
                error = null,
                contentDescription = "The delasign logo",
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .background(Color.Black)
            )
        }
    }

I tried to insert an additional overlay to disable the child scroll.
BoxWithConstraints(modifier = modifier) {
            val overlayWidth = constraints.maxWidth * 0.1f
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(overlayWidth.dp)
                    .fillMaxHeight()
                    .background(Color.Red)
            )
        }


Question should provide wider context of the problem for better understanding a matter

I need to enable pageCurl to scroll to the next new image in the row, and when I get to the second image, enable pageCurl to scroll instead of scrolling from the row, and also when I'm on the first image in the row, so that I can return to the previous image from pageCurl and that I can go to image number 2 within the row.
